# How Can I Log Into a Web Forms Website Before Parsing with Simple HTML Dom Parser?

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

### Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I need to scrape product data from this website, but the pricing is different when you are logged in. Thus, I need to submit this login form (via php), then use [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) to scrape the product data.

### I have found the following similar posts:

- [Simple HTML DOM Parser - Send post variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497153/simple-html-dom-parser-send-post-variables)
- [Authorize with curl and parse using simple html dom not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186768/authorize-with-curl-and-parse-using-simple-html-dom-not-working)
- [Login to ASP website before using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297687/login-to-asp-website-before-using-php-simple-html-dom-parser)
- [Processing HTTP Post with Array (no cURL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823046/processing-http-post-with-array-no-curl)
- [Using PHP & Curl to login to my websites form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049393/using-php-curl-to-login-to-my-websites-form)
- [php curl script to get an aspx page's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719095/php-curl-script-to-get-an-aspx-pages-content)
- https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

However, none of the answers have allowed me to login and proceed to scrape while logged into the following site:
https://www.bestlinknetware.com/Account/LogOn

### What I Have Tried

***Attempt #1***

```
$data = http_build_query(array(
          "UserName" => "ourValidUsername",
          "Password" => "ourValidPassword"
        ));

send_message("<p>" . $data . "</p>");

$request = array(
  "http" => array(
    "header" => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n".
                "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n",
    "method" => "POST",
    "content" => $data
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($request);

$html = file_get_contents( $crawl["url"] . "/Account/LogOn", false, $context, -1, 40000 );

echo $html;
```

***Attempt #2***

```
$url = "https://www.bestlinknetware.com/Account/LogOn"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$data = array(
  "UserName" => "ourValidUsername",
  "Password" => "ourValidPassword"
);

$postData = http_build_query($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/4");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 2);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

Both of the above attempts resulted in (seemingly) nothing happening. The page just shows the login form... I can't tell if the login attempt is failing, or if I need to do something like (after the cURL POST), add `$html = file_get_html("http://www.bestlinknetware.com/");` and begin the parsing...

***Note:** When I simply add the `$html = file_Get_html("...")` script, I can scrape the site, but I get the regular (non-logged in) prices...*

Can anyone with experience using Simple HTML DOM Parser shed some light on the proper way to submit POST data to login form like this, then load the post-login HTML into the Simple HTML DOM Parser object (so that I can scrape it)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17')));
$html = str_get_html( file_get_contents('http://page.com/user1', false, $context) );
```